# How to join two collection and transpose a collection as an entity using LINQ (c#)

Tags: c#, linq, join, pivot, transpose

I have the following classes:

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
public class Marks
{
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public string Score { get; set; }
}
```

Populating the collection:

```
Collection<Student> objStudentCollection = new Collection<Student>();
Student student = new Student();
student.StudentID = "104517";
student.StudentName = "John";
objStudentCollection.Add(student);

student = new Student();
student.StudentID = "104520";
student.StudentName = "Stella";
objStudentCollection.Add(student);

Collection<Marks> objMarkCollection = new Collection<Marks>();
Marks marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104517";
marks.SubjectName = "English";
marks.Score = "85";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);

marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104517";
marks.SubjectName = "Science";
marks.Score = "60";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);


marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104517";
marks.SubjectName = "Mathematics";
marks.Score = "75";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);


marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104517";
marks.SubjectName = "Optional 1";
marks.Score = "75";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);


marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104520";
marks.SubjectName = "French";
marks.Score = "54";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);

marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104520";
marks.SubjectName = "Science";
marks.Score = "60";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);


marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104520";
marks.SubjectName = "Mathematics";
marks.Score = "75";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);


marks = new Marks();
marks.StudentID = "104520";
marks.SubjectName = "Optional 1";
marks.Score = "50";
objMarkCollection.Add(marks);
```

I would like to bind the above collections in GridView to display like:

> StudentID | StudentName | English | French | Mathematics | Science | Optional 1 | Total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to utilise the [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx) method to get what you're after.
You could do it like this if the list of subjects if fixed and not going to change:

```
var q = 
  objStudentCollection
  .GroupJoin(
    objMarkCollection,
    stu => stu.StudentID,
    mark => mark.StudentID,
    (stu, mark) =>
        new
        {
            student.StudentID,
            student.StudentName,
            English = mark.Where(m => m.SubjectName == "English").Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
            French  = mark.Where(m => m.SubjectName == "French").Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
            Mathematics  = mark.Where(m => m.SubjectName == "Mathematics").Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
            Science   = mark.Where(m => m.SubjectName == "Science").Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
            Optional1  = mark.Where(m => m.SubjectName == "Optional 1").Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
            Total = mark.Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)),
        })
```

It's not the prettiest code in the world, but it will give you an anonymous type with each row containing data you asked for. You could replace `Sum` with `SingleOrDefault` if there is only ever one mark per subject.

```
var subjects = 
    objMarkCollection
    .Select(mark => mark.SubjectName)
    .Distinct()
    .Dump();

var q =  
    objStudentCollection 
    .GroupJoin( 
        objMarkCollection, 
        stu => stu.StudentID, 
        mark => mark.StudentID, 
        (stu, mark) => 
            new 
            { 
                student.StudentID, 
                student.StudentName, 
                Marks = 
                    from s in subjects
                    join m in mark on s equals m.SubjectName into outer
                    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        SubjectName = s,
                        Score = (o == null) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(o.Score),
                    },
                Total = mark.Sum(m => Convert.ToInt32(m.Score)), 
            }) 
    .Dump();
```

This 2nd solution will create you an anonymous type with each student and a collection of marks including each subject (those the student has not take will have a 0 score).